# Joint measurability of a Brownian motion

Tags: measure-theory, brownian-motion, measurable-functions

Hi I am not that familiar in proving measurability of a function. The definition I know is that the preimage of measurable sets has to be measurable again. But how to prove that seems difficult to me at the first glance. I do have the following exercise: Let $(B_t)$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ with continuous trajectories/paths.
Consider the product space $$([0,\infty),\mathcal{B}_{[0,\infty)},\lambda)\otimes (\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$$

where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Show that the mapping $(t,\omega)\rightarrow (B_t(\omega))$($t\geq 0$)
defined from that space to $(\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}})$ is measurable. How can I prove this? I think the continuity is important, but I dont know how to involve it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First, maybe you should make some simplifications. For example, you don't need to check every preimage, just some generating sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approximate $B(t,\omega)$ by the sequence of simple processes $\{B^{(n)}(t,\omega)=B(2^{-n}\lfloor 2^{n}t\rfloor,\omega)\}$. It is easy to see that $(t,\omega)\mapsto B^{(n)}(t,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{B}_{[0,\infty)}\otimes\mathcal{A}$-measurable and $B^{(n)}\to B$ pointwise as $n\to\infty$ ($\because$ $B$ is continuous). Thus, $B$ is also measurable as the limit of measurable functions.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but I'm having a few troubles. First why do choose $2^n \left \lfloor{t 2^-n}\right \rfloor$ for $n$ big enough that would always get to $0$. Did you mean it the other way round? And secondly, it is unfortunately not that easy to see, that $B^{n}(t,\omega)$ is measurable in the sense I would wish. Can you clarify that a bit more please?

Comment: Oh. It should be $2^{-n} \left \lfloor{t 2^n}\right \rfloor$ instead. Also, one can write
$$
B^{(n)}(t,\omega)=\sum_{k\ge 0} B(k2^{-n},\omega)1_{[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})}(t),
$$
which is jointly measurable.